# attempt to download "readr" package unsuccessful

Tags: r

This is what the code is looking like after attempting to download the "readr" package. Nothing I can find has helped troubleshoot

```
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lazyeval’ had non-zero exit status
Warning message:
In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so
  Reason: image not found
* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
* removing ‘/Users/JoseM/Library/R/3.3/library/Rcpp’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
Warning message:
In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so
  Reason: image not found
ERROR: dependencies ‘lazyeval’, ‘Rcpp’ are not available for package ‘tibble’
* removing ‘/Users/JoseM/Library/R/3.3/library/tibble’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tibble’ had non-zero exit status
Warning message:
In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so
  Reason: image not found
ERROR: dependencies ‘Rcpp’, ‘tibble’ are not available for package ‘readr’
* removing ‘/Users/JoseM/Library/R/3.3/library/readr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘readr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/j1/_dcr13gs1_b0wn3z_1lvd09w0000gn/T/RtmpWFlOtM/downloaded_packages’
>
```

Comment: It looks like Command Line Tools aren't installed correctly. Is this macOS?

Comment: yes this is on a macOS, what would you recommend?

Comment: I think there's a shortcut that just `xcode-select --install` in Terminal will do it, or you can [download them from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action), though you'll need to make a developer account (which should be free).